# Problems Clipping Raster to Polygon

Tags: raster

I am working on a project involving reforestation issues. I have my raster (showing a large community) and a polygon representing the specific area of study. I tried using the clip raster tool, but it is not giving me the expected results...the raster is still much larger than the polygon and the tool did not clip exactly to the area of study. I have attached a photo showing. Any ideas on how to fix this or another tool I should be using instead? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check the 'Use Input Features for Clipping Geometry' option :)